# ArcMap Extension GetTempPath returns with an extra SubFolder

Tags: .net, arcgis, esri, arcmap

I am creating an installable extension for ArcMap using C#/WPF/VS2010. (which may or may not have any bearing here).  One thing I would like to do is store data in the users temporary folder.  So, I get the folder like so:

```
public static string SystemTempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
```

When I compile everything and Bind to the variable (indirectly) in the WPF designer I got this in the preview pane:

```
"C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\"
```

Great, thats what I am after.  But when I run the extension in ArcMap I get something like the following:

```
"C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\arcA6C5\"
```

Note the extra folder at the end which changes every time I reload ArcMap.  So it seems that since this is an extension and I am somewhat at the mercy of the ArcMap kernel, it is using ArcMap's created temp folder and not the user temp var.

My question:  Is there a way to get around this grammatically other then a string manipulation?  I could assume that this extra will always be there and simply truncate but this way seems somewhat dirty.  I have tried this as well with the same result:

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP");
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TMP");
```

Which would only be slightly less dirty anyway.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that ArcMap is changing it's runtime environment (the `TEMP` and `TMP` environment variables) to create a unique temp folder for each run.  Any Windows API call to retrieve the temp folder will return the updated ones (by design).

> One thing I would like to do is store data in the users temporary folder.

I would recommend storing the data within the [user's application data folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) instead.  This is an appropriate place to store user data, and will be consistent.  Try something like:

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
path = Path.Combine(path, @"YourCompany\YourProduct\");
```

Comment: Thanks Reed.  Thats what I figured.  I was liking the idea of using the Temp folder so it can be cleanup with all the other user temp files (if and when then happens).  I already have a app data folder for storing settings but if I use then then I have to worry about it cleaning it up.  Have to think about it some more.